# How do I get SQL Server agent to show up in SSMS

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server Express edition and I want to learn job in sql server but ssms is not showing sql agent. so help me

Comment: You have to get standard edition of `SQL Server` for that. `SQL Agent` is not available with `SQL Express`

Comment: thanks  u so much raj sir